# no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: mysql, oracle, dbms

My parent table

```
Create table spare(
Sid int ,
Sname varchar(20),
Mid int,
primary key(Sid,Sname),
foreign key(Mid) references manu(Mid) on delete cascade

);
```

My child table

```
Create table Branch(
Bid int primary key,
Loc varchar(20),
Sid int,
Sname varchar(20),
foreign key(Sid) references spare(Sid),
foreign key(Sname) references spare(Sname) 
);
```

I have made the references to the primary keys itseld but I'm still getting this error

Comment: which database? you've tagged both mysql and oracle.  most solutions to most questions are specific to a particular rdbms product.

Answer (score 2):

you have a combined Primanry key.
So use

```
Create table Branch(
Bid int primary key,
Loc varchar(20),
Sid int,
Sname varchar(20),
foreign key(Sid,Sname) references spare(Sid,Sname)
);
```

Or you define in your spare table two new indexes for the column, so you can have different foreign keys